# Making a query through ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server

If I have my data an ArcGIS Server and I don't want to bring all the data, but I want to make a query first to select group some data together then bring only the result. How can I make that as the records number is huge and I don't want the records, I want only the result of grouping them together?

For example: If you have lands, each assigned with for a specific use (agricultural, industrial, etc..), the number of records is huge, you have a website that filters the lands with their location, use, or both, and the result is only the the percentage area of the filtered data w.r.t the total area. So you don't want to bring all the data you want only the result. How to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at using the [Summary Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) geoprocessing tool.

What you need to do is to [publish this as a Geoprocessing service](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/a-quick-tour-of-publishing-a-geoprocessing-service.htm), and while publishing it, you can set the inputs according to your needs.

Any client can then consume this service, and get the results, which are just summary of the data after grouping